# Auto lock does not function when app left open - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, auto-lock

I'm developing a messaging app and auto lock doesn't function when app left open. (No single line is related to auto lock in code)

I've used this line to enabling it,

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:NO];
```

but its not working.

Any idea how to get this done?

Comment: give more details

Comment: i think its enough. let me know if anything else  required ?

Comment: Is auto lock enabled in the iOS settings?

Comment: Are you playing or downloading any kind of media stream - audio or video in your app, or continuously updating some UI component?

Comment: Just curious, are you connected to and running through Xcode? Or do you see it even when Xcode is not running the app? In my experience, the device will not lock while running in the debugger unless your app is in the background.

Comment: @chiris yes, auto lock is enabled in settings & no media streaming. I'm trying it on a screen with static UI.

Comment: @samantha. you were right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For anyone who is facing the same issue.

> The device will not lock when you are running app through X-code
>   either debugging or not. Once app is installed you have to detach it
>   from X-code( *just remove the attached cable* ), it will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

For others who may encounter this, in my case, it was the AVPlayer who prevented the display from going to sleep.
To solve this, use the [preventsDisplaySleepDuringVideoPlayback](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/2990522-preventsdisplaysleepduringvideop?language=objc) property of AVPlayer:

```
    let player = AVPlayer()
    player.preventsDisplaySleepDuringVideoPlayback = false
```

Comment: that would probably would lead to a rejection to publish to the app store :(